# @Valid (javax.validation.Valid) is not recursive for the type of list

Tags: java, spring-boot, spring-mvc, hibernate-validator, javax.validation

Controller:

```java
@RequestMapping(...)
public void foo(@Valid Parent p){
}
```

```java
class Parent {
  @NotNull // javax.validation.constraints.NotNull
  private String name;
  List<Child> children;
}
```

```
class Child {
  @NotNull
  private String name;
}
```

This triggers `@NotNull` for Parent.name but doesn't check for Child.name.
How to make it trigger. I tried `List<@Valid Child> children;` also annotate Child class with `@Valid` annotation, doesn't work. Please help.

`parent = { "name": null }` fails. name can't be null.

`child = { "name": null }` works.

Comment: Sorry, problem was something else. I wasn't checking the errors right.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

Have you tried it like this:

```
class Parent {
    @NotNull // javax.validation.constraints.NotNull
    private String name;

    @Valid
    List<Child> children;
}
```

Comment: Yes, this doesn't work as well. Looks this validates the list, not it's type.

Comment: Well this should actually work as described here: https://beanvalidation.org/1.0/spec/#constraintdeclarationvalidationprocess-validationroutine-graphvalidation And I guess the other answers second that.

Answer (score 2):

Try adding,

```
class Parent {
    @NotNull 
    private String name;

    @NotNull 
    @Valid
    List<Child> children;
}
```

Answer (score 2):

If you want to validate the child then you have to mention @Valid to the attribute itself

### Parent Class

```java
class Parent {
  @NotNull // javax.validation.constraints.NotNull
  private String name;

  @NotNull // Not necessary if it's okay for children to be null
  @Valid // javax.validation.Valid
  privateList<Child> children;
}
```

### Child class

```java
class Child {
  @NotNull
  private String name;
}
```

Answer (score 1):

With Bean Validation 2.0 and Hibernate Validator 6.x, it is recommended to use:

```
class Parent {
    @NotNull 
    private String name;

    List<@Valid Child> children;
}
```

We support `@Valid` and constraints in container elements.

However, what the others suggested should work.

Answer (score 0):

`annotate` in `Parent` your list with `@Valid` and add `@NotEmpty` or `@NotBlank` or `@NotNull` to `Child`. Spring will validate it just fine.

```
class Parent {
    @NotNull // javax.validation.constraints.NotNull
    private String name;

    @Valid
    List<Child> children;
}

class Child {
  @NotNull
  private String name;
}
```